# I have multiple domains, is there any way for them to share the same cookie

Tags: javascript

I own domain `a.com`, `b.com`, `c.com`. They are part of the same network. With safari 11, and more privacy oriented browsers, when someone has a cookie on a.com, it doesn't transfer over when they visit b.com unless they explicitly sign-on again. Is there any way to keep cookies persistent, across the three domains?

Comment: Learn about single-sign-on systems.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Comment: *"With safari 11, and more privacy oriented browsers, it doesn't transfer over when they visit b.com"* -- it is not because of the privacy orientation of the modern browsers. This is how the cookies were designed when they were introduced (by the Netscape browser) back in the 90s.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) for more details and solutions on cross-domain cookies.